# Scrapy CrawlSpider : deny subdomain won't work, why?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy and trying to crawl `www.google.com/.*`.
I programmed the following spider, but it still visits subdomains like `support.google.com`. What am I missing?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class GoogleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'google'
    allowed_domains = ['www.google.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.google.com']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
                  allow=[r"^http[s]?://www.google.com/.*"]),
                  callback='parse_item',
                  follow = True)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('Processing {}'.format(response.url))
```

*Note*: there were too many debug outputs, so I added the line `LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR'` in `settings.py` and I'm using `print` to see which webpage is visited.

This script prints subdomain urls such as `support.google.com`, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
allowed_domains = ['google.com']
```

only instead of `allowed_domains = ['www.google.com']`